# JCL tag has multiple meanings

Tags: discussion, tags

The tag [jcl](/questions/tagged/jcl) has, if I can count correctly, 4 different meanings at the moment.

1. Job Control Language, for IBM mainframes.  The tag wiki refers to this one
2. Java Constraints Library
3. JEDI Code Library - Appears to be related to Delphi
4. Jakarta Commons Logging - tag already exists, [jakarta-commons-logging](/questions/tagged/jakarta-commons-logging)

My proposal is to introduce two new tags for the Java Constraints Library and the JEDI Code Library, and move the appropriate questions over to those.  There is already a tag for Jakarta Commons Logging, so any questions relating to that can be moved to that tag.  That would leave just IBM's JCL at the JCL tag.  How does that sound?

Comment: And the above is complete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I concur with your suggestion to introduce two new tags, but I think this is an excellent example of an idea I've been kicking around -- thinking about asking:

Could we perhaps introduce a [Wikipedia style disambiguation pop-up](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Disambiguation) for the [jcl](/questions/tagged/jcl) tag? as well as others?  This would also be a possible solution to prevent future questions from jumping into the [jcl](/questions/tagged/jcl) confusingly.

Comment: I'd be interested in how you'd present this disambiguation popup, because it's an interesting idea but it'd have to be presented to the user in such a way that it's not cumbersome

Comment: gimp is giving me seg-faults...  I was thinking of a section labelled 'disambiguation' separated from the usual tag-completion using a horizontal line.  So that, for example, [tag:compass] would still auto-complete to [tag:compass-lucene], but the disambiguation would also show [tag:lucene-compass].  Which I realize isn't the best example because these should just be synonyms anyways, but I hope it conveys the idea.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea - can you add a feature request for this?

Comment: [I just did.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100070/)  Feel free to edit/make any suggestions for improvement!  :)