# Should [jedi] and [jedi-code-library] be synonyms?

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

[jedi](/questions/tagged/jedi) and [jedi-code-library](/questions/tagged/jedi-code-library) seem, to my non-Delphi savvy eye, to be about the same thing.

Should these be merged/synonymed?  We [recently moved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99898/jcl-tag-has-multiple-meanings) a bunch of questions to [jedi-code-library](/questions/tagged/jedi-code-library) from [jcl](/questions/tagged/jcl), and the [jedi](/questions/tagged/jedi) questions seem to be quite similar.  I'm guessing that [jedi](/questions/tagged/jedi) -> [jedi-code-library](/questions/tagged/jedi-code-library) would be the correct direction here, if a merge or synonym is in order.

Comment: What is the correct tag for lightsaber-wielding users of the Force?

Comment: Jedi would be the correct tag, but not on SO unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Jedi", in this case, is a reference to *[Project Jedi](http://www.delphi-jedi.org/)*, which is a name for a group of projects that are in some way related to each other, such as JEDI Code Library (JCL), JEDI Visual Component Library (JVCL), JEDI Version Control System, and JEDI Quicktime project.

Between all the questions tagged [jedi](/questions/tagged/jedi), I can see there are some questions that are about  JVCL, not JCL.

- [Is it possible to control how tabs are displayed in the JvDockServer component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6630607/is-it-possible-to-control-how-tabs-are-displayed-in-the-jvdockserver-component)
- [Delphi 6/JEDI-JVCL - Not getting custom message form with detailed stack dump anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367109/delphi-6-jedi-jvcl-not-getting-custom-message-form-with-detailed-stack-dump-any)

There are also questions about Jedi VCS.

- [How to undelete a module from a JEDI Version System project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831970/how-to-undelete-a-module-fro-a-jedi-version-system-project)
- [How can I delete (with a trick) projects in JEDI VCS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341590/how-to-delete-with-a-trick-projects-in-jedi-vcs)

Retagging questions that use [jedi](/questions/tagged/jedi) with [jedi-code-library](/questions/tagged/jedi-code-library) cannot be automatically done; at least, some of the questions should use a different tag; even supposing that there is no need to use a specific tag for Jedi VCS, there is still the need of a tag for the Jedi VCL.
Actually, there is already [jvcl](/questions/tagged/jvcl), which is used for 17 questions, but not from all the questions that are about Jedi VCL.

Probably, we should:

- rename [jvcl](/questions/tagged/jvcl) using a similar name used for [jedi-code-library](/questions/tagged/jedi-code-library)
- retag the questions using [jedi](/questions/tagged/jedi) with the most appropriate tag

Comment: Thanks @kiamlaluno.  I'll wait another day or so in case anyone has other ideas, then make it happen.