# Doesn't the Stack Exchange community support mainframe related questions?

Tags: support

I see that Super User doesn't have any questions tagged *Mainframes*, or *COBOL*, or *JCL*, nor have I seen mainframe related support on Stack Overflow.

Does that mean that the Stack Exchange community does not support mainFrames and related development, or does it simply mean that no one has ever asked such a question before?

Personally, I feel that [JCL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_Control_Language), COBOL, [CICS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CICS), being vast fields, would certainly benefit from Stack Exchange's community support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There certainly are mainframe programming-related questions on SO - for example, we had a fun time pulling Delphi-related questions out of [jcl](/questions/tagged/jcl) and into their own tag, after a discussion about it [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99898/jcl-tag-has-multiple-meanings).

For hardware support, I would agree with ChrisF that SF probably makes more sense than SU.  SF [does have](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/mainframe) some mainframe-related questions, though not many.

Comment: Thanks dsolimano! I wasn't looking for hardware support; merely code related queries from JCL and COBOL programming. I'll post on SO.

Answer (score 1):

It can mean one of three things (and you had two of them right):

1. There simply have not been any questions about them yet.
2. There *have* been questions, but they were deleted and so were the tags after a while.
3. There's been a discussion on Meta.SU deeming those subjects off-topic for SU.

I haven't looked into it yet, but if it's the first two, then you have the liberty to post questions about them. Make sure you phrase them well and generally follow the advice given in the faq for the site.

If you don't know which it is, then dig around on the site's Meta and find a post relating to it. If it's been discussed, then you're in luck, and it will definitely guide you in the right direction. If it's the third, and the meta post confirmed that, then that's where it ends.